# MongoDB aggregation query in RapidMiner

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, rapidminer

How to do an aggregation query in MongoDB from the RapidMiner using the mongodb plugin? I've tried to google around, unfortunately with no success at all. It has a direct support for criteria and projection (using operator "Read MongoDB"), however I don't see anyhow support for the aggregation. It does have an "Execute MongoDB Command" operator, which might be capable of doing that but I can't find any extensive examples on how to use it. Eventually, if the above mentioned is not possible, do you know any other way how to do the "unwind" over the data in the RapidMiner having the mongodb collection loaded in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Execute MongoDB Command* Operator is a wrapper for the mongoDB command [db.runCommand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.runCommand/).  If you want to continue working in RapidMiner, you can expand the collection you get as a result from the *Read MongoDB* and transform it into an ExampleSet with the *JSON to Data* Operator.